# Technology to read TCP socket in Google Chrome

Tags: sockets, google-chrome, tcp, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-app

I am looking for the latest technology in Google Chrome to read a TCP socket on the users computer and capture the data (which I will then manipulate and populate a field on the web page.) I have read about NPAPI, chrome apps and chrome extensions but each is either about to be deprecated or doesn't support TCP sockets. What method is available that will be supported for more than the next year?

I have already developed a similar addon for Internet Explorer in ActiveX that is called in javascript and works well.

Comment: Maybe WebSockets API? Otherwise a native OS program + extension + [nativeMessaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging) seems the only choice.

Comment: Thanks @wOxxOm I am taking a look at the websockets API. Unfortunately I do not want to use a native OS program because I want the user experience the be in the browser entirely the way I have it working in IE.

Comment: FWIW, a hidden native OS program would provide the backend communication functionality, while your extension would present the data inside the browser. This is how nativeMessaging works usually.